# Oracle database is hanging infinitly in UPDATE queries

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, oracle11g

suddenly my update queries are not executing  . i can make  **select** queries but when i try to **update** records the database hangs infinitly. i tried even from sql plus and nothing happens.

Comment: Please, can you be more explicit? There is no way we can *guess* what's going on on your system. What do you know? What have you checked? How does your system work, how many users, etc...? What does the update query look like? What kind of DML is running against the same table at the same time?

Comment: Can you log off and on again OK? Are you in ARCHIVELOG mode? Do you have uncommitted changes in another session locing your current update? A bit more information would be handy....

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most likely you have another open uncommitted transaction for the same set of records, so they are locked for that transaction.

And, most likely, **you** locked them, running the same `UPDATE` in another transaction.

Just Commit/rollback your transactions, you should be fine.

Comment: Now **that** answer is what I call an educated guess ;-)

Comment: Yes. Yes, it is. When you've been around for sometime and you coach beginners, you get that *the-force-is-strong-in-me* kinda vibe and you know their problems before they can tell you everything. :) But I'm not always right, of course.

Comment: I know that vibe. It goes well with "speak no further and observe" :)

Comment: Five years later... you saved a me a huge amount of time. I wrote a Python script with a query in it and couldn't figure out why it would hang on execution, but after reading this I realized I didn't commit after testing the query in SQL Developer. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh thank you! This just saved me as well! I was testing queries in SQL Developer and thought I had committed everything, but something was still uncommitted. Once I disconnected with SQL Developer it asked about committing changes, and after disconnect my python script worked :)

Answer (score 21):

This query will show you who is blocking your update. Execute the update that hangs, then in another session run this:

```
select s1.username || '@' || s1.machine ||
  ' ( SID=' || s1.sid || ' )  is blocking '
  || s2.username || '@' || s2.machine || ' ( SID=' || s2.sid || ' ) ' AS blocking_status
  from v$lock l1 join v$lock l2 on (l1.id1 = l2.id1 and l2.id2 = l2.id2) 
                 JOIN v$session s1 ON (s1.sid = l1.sid)
                 JOIN v$session s2 ON (s2.sid = l2.sid)
  WHERE l1.BLOCK=1 and l2.request > 0;
```

EDIT:

To properly attribute this, it looks like I cribbed this a while back from [ORAFAQ](http://orafaq.com/node/854).

Comment: I use it a lot. Wish I could remember where I found that one. Possibly a Tom Kyte special. Update: I think I got it here: http://orafaq.com/node/854

Comment: How can we stop or kill the resulting task?

Comment: Here's a good writeup:  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions

Comment: This query hung, too... what does that tell me?