# Updating Oracle DB via pyodbc hangs

Tags: python, oracle, pyodbc

I'm having issues with pyodbc used with an Oracle DB. I can do select statements with results coming back, however when I try to update a record, the program seems to hang during the "conn.execute(query)" line with no error messages. I have to force quit the application.

Running a select statement retrieves the expected result. Updating that same record will hang.
I've also used this definition on other applications with no issues on a MSSQL DB with selects and updates working properly. I've also checked that the user / pass do have read and write permissions

```py
import pyodbc

def connect_odbc(conn_str, query, commit=False):
    """
    Returns result set from connection string.
    If commit is set to true, it will write to DB as well
    """
    if commit:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)  ### <--- Program hangs here
        cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        return True
    else:
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.close()

        return results

## Main Program ##
query = "select * from multishipdtl where cartonid = '100000000060506';"
queryupdate = "update multishipdtl set trackid='88888888' where cartonid = '100000000060506';"

conn_str = '''DSN=syntest;UID=userid;PWD=userpass'''
results = connect_odbc(conn_str, query)  ### This connects ok with expected results

connect_odbc(conn_str, queryupdate, commit=True)  ### Update statement hangs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program hangs when executing `cursor.execute("UPDATE ...")`, the first thing I'd check is if it's waiting for the database to respond: [How do you show SQL executing on an Oracle database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8828/15599)

- If the DB shows your session running the UPDATE, most likely it's because another transaction has locked the rows you're trying to update - see [Oracle database is hanging infinitly in UPDATE queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7501776/1026); otherwise  [check `V$SESSION`'s `status` and `wait_time`, and `V$SESSION_WAIT`'s `event`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/140433/15599). You might also want to try to reproduce this by running the UPDATE from an SQL client (sans Python).
- If it's not the DB, check the Python's call stack for hints. It should be printed when you abort the program by pressing CTRL+C, if not - try [Showing the stack trace from a running Python application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29881630/1026)

An [ODBC trace log](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log) might be helpful too.